# Struct with an array prototype in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

What does this syntax mean in C?:

```
// for loop, ok no problem
for(i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++) {

    // this bit confuses me
    struct Address addr = {.id = i, .set = 0};

   // ... etc 

}
```

If my title is wrong please correct me because I didn't even know how to name this syntax.

I understand it that it's setting the id to the value of `i`, but why don't we write something like `addr.i`?

Thanks

Comment: just the syntax for initializing the fields of the `struct`. Writing `addr.*` in the brackets would be redundant,, we already know everything inside of `{ ... }` is dealing with `addr`. If you don't like that syntax you can just as easily do `struct Address addr; addr.id = i; addr.set = 0;`

Comment: @yano `addr = {.id = i, .set = 0};` initializes all members -- even ones not listed.  `addr.id = i; addr.set = 0;` assigned 2 of them.

Comment: @chux any other members are initialized to 0?

Comment: @yano integer members  are 0, FP and pointers do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
struct Address addr = {.id = i, .set = 0};
```

uses a *designated initializer* to set the `id` and `set` fields of the `addr` variable.  This syntax is only valid in a definition, or as part of a compound literal.

It's roughly equivalent to writing

```
struct Address addr;

addr.id = 1;
addr.set = 0;
```

Comment: An important difference between `struct Address addr = {.id = i, .set = 0};` and `struct Address addr;

addr.id = 1;
addr.set = 0;` is that the first initialized all members whereas the later  assigned only two.